# NumPy - fastest way to check if array is a view of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have array `a` and possibly a view `v` of it. What is the fastest (and maybe easiest) way to check if `v` is really a view of `a`, not a copy?

I see there is [np.shares_memory](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html) but it is said in this doc that function sometimes may be exponentially slow.

I assume that views are lightweight references to original array, and writing to views always changing original array (BTW, is it the correct assumption?).

E.g. `v = a[1:5]` is a view, but `v = a[[1,3,6]]` is not.

If `v` is a view, then doing `v[...] = [1,2,3]` should always change original array too, if it is not a view, then doing this operation changes just a copy of `a`.

So I want to be sure, `assert` somehow, that doing `v[...] = [1,2,3]` will change original array too, i.e. I want to assert that `v` is a view of `a`.

Comment: Is it *exponentially slow* for your use-case? Have you profiled it?

Comment: @Divakar No, I have a simple case. I'm just learning the correct way. If it is a canonical way to check the view then I'll use it even if it is slow. But as I'm still learning, I wanted to remember once the correct way of doing this and use it later always. Or at least to hear what are different ways of doing this.

Comment: @Divakar Also I thought that a view is always stored internally as original (same) pointer plus maybe offset plus slice plus shape. So it could be just checked by comparing that pointer is same. But probably it is not.

Comment: I look at the arr.__array_interface__`.  If the `data` number overlaps, I think itps a view.  But I haven't tried to test this in code.

Comment: @hpaulj One application of this check is next - if some function `f(a)` returned a view of `a` and I've changed some elements of this view, how can I be sure (`assert`) that original `a` had also these changes (I don't know exact positions in original array so I can't compare if these elements have changed).